# Use OAuth or Public Key API for private YouTube application?

Tags: php, api, oauth, youtube

I would like to create an application using PHP that would authenticate to only my YouTube account/channel to create playlists, upload and play videos/playlists which would be set to Private. For now, users will not be logging into their own YouTube accounts and my application will not access their information.

Should I use OAuth or the Public Key API? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Is it necessary that the user interacts with OAuth?

What are the implications with the Public Key if the application is on a shared hosting web server (many customers having the same IP address)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must* use OAuth if you want to access or modify any private data, e.g. upload videos.

After all, you are the (one) user who has to authorize remote access on behalf of your account.

API Keys are only used for retrieving public data and wouldn't get you far in your case.

As long as you use your designated url (e.g. 'mydomain.net/myyoutubeapp), there won't be any problems on a shared hosting web server.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. From there, is it possible for my server app to authenticate on behalf of me  without user intervention in order to proceed with a command? If so, are there any PHP code samples of this?

Answer (score 2):

The public key and OAuth are both useful but for different need

With the public key, you can just fetch the public information you can normally access on Youtube without being authenticated like search, view videos, get the public information about a user/a playlist/a video, read comments.

If you use OAuth, you'll be able to manage your user's account, playlist, favorites song etc. You are just limited to the permission your users accepted like upload a video on his account, post a comment etc. So, you can do all what you're allowed to do with a public key + the action authorized by the user. But to use OAuth, you have to redirect your user to the authorization form of youtube:

[image]

and then, if the user accept, you'll have the access granted to do what you're allowed to with the permissions you asked for.

There is not advantage or disadvantage of both methods, just depends of what you need for your application

In your case, you should use OAuth to generate a valid access_token and a refresh_token for your account if you want to upload videos and manage your playlist. When your access_token expire, you can generate a new one without display the authorization popup with the refresh_token.

Comment: I need to fetch data from a Google Analytics account (many devices should be connected to one account). Can I use public key for the authentication?

Comment: Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication
You need to use OAuth to be authorized to retrieve data from Google Analytics. You can use https://oauth.io to ease the way you connect with Google analytics

Comment: "Before users can view **their** account information on the Google Analytics web site, they must first log in with a Google Account. In the same way, when users first access your application, they need to authorize your application to access **their** data." @Thibaud, I don't think OAuth can be used to authorize many users to get data from one specific account.

Comment: You have multiple way to do it: you can 1) add multiple user to your Google Analytics account (and the comment above works), if they are registered in GA, they'll be authorized to retrieve data from it. Or 2) you can use another flow of OAuth, a server to server flow using JWT to authorize your app instead of your user which is described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount. Both can works, after, it depends of your need.