# Upload Video to YouTube in Swift

Tags: swift, rest, video, youtube, upload

EDIT: Still checking this frequently, will mark as solved when I or someone else helps me figure it out!

I am trying to upload a video to YouTube with YouTube’s REST API via Swift but I am having great difficulty figuring out what to do. I currently have a working GET request.

I'm confused on how the POST request URL should be constructed and where the file location is meant to go in the request. Also I think I should be using the resumbable upload protocol?

I have been struggling through various API's and documentation for 2 days now and am feeling hopeless.

Here is my working code for a GET request.

```
func getRequestVideoInfo(){
    // Set up your URL
    let youtubeApi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails%2C+snippet%2C+statistics&id=AKiiekaEHhI&key=" + apiKey
    let url = NSURL(string: youtubeApi)

    // Create your request
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            if let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject] {

                print("Response from YouTube: \(jsonResult)")
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }

    })

    // Start the request
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**HEADS UP (as of October 6, 2019)**
YouTube has decreased the API quota to 10,000 units per day. This is the equivalent of uploading 4 YouTube videos during a 24 hour time span. If your application use case relies on uploading many YouTube videos, I strongly advise you to reconsider. You can apply for an expansion of your daily quota, but Google is notoriously slow at getting back to you, if they do at all.

---

Yes, you need to create an app/project in YouTube and use the OAuth 2.0 Flow to post/insert videos to a channel to which you receive authorized access.

ONCE YOU HAVE YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM GOOGLE

use Alamofire as follows:

```
func postVideoToYouTube(token: String, callback: Bool -> Void){

    let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "mp4")
    let videodata: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)! as! NSData
    upload(
        .POST,
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id",
        headers: headers,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: videodata, name: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { request, response, error in
                    print(response)
                    callback(true)
                }
            case .Failure(_):
                callback(false)
            }
        })
}
```

Call the post function like this:

```
postVideoToYouTube(accessToken, callback: { success in
if success { }
})
```

Comment: 1) have you created an iOS project in the Google Developers Console  2) have you set up and configured a URL Scheme in your app's info.plist as a CFBundleURLSchemes for the redirect URI, 3) do you have your google project's client id and client secret?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert.   inserting a video with POST requires authorization as noted in this guide link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734022/use-oauth-or-public-key-api-for-private-youtube-application

Comment: 1) Yep. 2) If you mean the bundle ID then yes. 3) Yes.

Comment: See my edit above for a POST example using Alamofire

Comment: @mrkbxt do you have any idea how to also set a snippet with title and description? It never accepts my snippet.

Comment: @user3344977. Are you setting 1) part=snippet and 2) adding the nested  "snippet": {"title": "VALUE",  "description": "VALUE", "tags": "VALUE", "categoryId": "VALUE",etc..} to the request inline after the '?' -or-  separately with multipartFormData.appendBodyPart()

Comment: @mrkbxt Thank you for responding and I really appreciate the help. I've opened a new question, rather than clutter these comments: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36190397/3344977

Comment: @mrkbxt I'm trying both of your suggestions right now and can't get either to work. Would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: @user3344977 multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"{'snippet':{'title' : 'TITLE_TEXT', 'description': 'DESCRIPTION_TEXT'}}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"snippet", mimeType: "application/json")

Comment: Is it possible to upload directly to youtube channel without showing/asking sign-in window? Is there a way to sign-in silently when user enter this screen?

Comment: If anyone is having difficulty getting the token with the whole OAuth2 flow, you can use this python script and it will spit one out for you that you can use in your Swift app. Obviously this isn't robust, but gets something working... https://gist.github.com/technoplato/4d28f4f308ea7c5fe20bd23e751e9e60

Comment: @lustig get error 

["error": {
    code = 403;
    errors =     (
                {
            domain = global;
            message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.";
            reason = insufficientPermissions;
        }
    );
    message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.";
}]

How can i solve this?

Comment: @YogendraPatel sounds like you didn't set up your API key properly

Comment: @lustig Thank you for help me. can you please say how can i set proper API key?

Comment: @YogendraPatel I'd appreciate if you made an attempt to check the docs for yourself. The future you will thank you as well. Check them out :)

Answer (score 2):

import GoogleSignIn

import GoogleAPIClientForREST

```
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeYouTube,
                      kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeForceSsl,
                      kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeUpload,
                      kGTLRAuthScopeYouTubeYoutubepartner]

private var service = GTLRYouTubeService()
private let youtubeObject = GTLRYouTube_Video()

func signInYoutube(){
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.clientID = "Your_client_id"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
     if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.hasPreviousSignIn() ?? false {
         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.restorePreviousSignIn()
     } else {
         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
     }
}
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
     if let error = error {
        self.service.authorizer = nil
       } else {
            self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
           uploadVideoOnYoutube()
       }
}
  func uploadVideoOnYoutube() {
        guard let videoUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample_iTunes", withExtension: "mov")else {return}

        //Status
        let status = GTLRYouTube_VideoStatus()
        status.privacyStatus = kGTLRYouTube_ChannelStatus_PrivacyStatus_Public
        //Snippet
        let snippet = GTLRYouTube_VideoSnippet()
        snippet.title = "YOUR_VIDEO_TITLE"

        //Upload parameters
        let params = GTLRUploadParameters.init(fileURL: videoUrl, mimeType: "video/mov")

        //YouTube Video object
        youtubeObject.status = status
        youtubeObject.snippet = snippet

        let query = GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosInsert.query(withObject: youtubeObject, part: "snippet,status", uploadParameters: params)

        service.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, anyobject, error) in
            if error == nil {
            if let videoObject = anyobject as? GTLRYouTube_Video {
                print(videoObject.identifier ?? "upload")
            }
     } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing great code. But I'm wondering if i should receive permission from Youtube when i only want to upload video. Because when i call `uploadVideoOnYoutube`, there is error 401. It means `unauthorized`. If you know answer, please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Permissions is Scope that you are already set on top.

Comment: I mean if i need `uploadVideoOnYoutube` method only, then I don't need to need to create `signInYoutube` and to set scopes for `GIDSignIn`. So I put apiKey into `GTLRYouTubeService`. Then I got HTTP error 401. But you mean I should set scope to GIDSignIn even though I don't need to provide Google sign in for use?

Comment: + I found out that user should login when they want to upload video on youtube if i use `GTLRYouTubeService`. So Is there another way to upload video on youtube application? I used universal link opening url `youtube://upload`, but it cannot select specific content. If you know the solution, please let me know. Thank you!