# Setting snippet data for youtube upload via REST API using Swift

Tags: swift, rest, video, youtube, alamofire

I'm able to successfully upload a video to youtube via their REST API using the following code:

```
func postVideoToYouTube(token: String, callback: Bool -> Void){

let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "mp4")
let videodata: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(path!)! as! NSData
upload(
    .POST,
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=id",
    headers: headers,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: videodata, name: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { request, response, error in
                print(response)
                callback(true)
            }
        case .Failure(_):
            callback(false)
        }
    })
}
```

I now would like to edit the above code so that I can set some `snippet` data on the initial upload, specifically a `title` and `description`.

I tried using an alternative `Alamofire` method that's very similar to the one above, only it also takes an `NSMutableURLRequest` as a parameter. I crafted my snippet dictionary and set it as the `HTTPBody` property of the mutable request. The video upload still works, but my snippet's title and description values are still not being set.

How can I set some snippet info when uploading the video to youtube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line to the multipartFormData block for the parameter values as follows (place the code before the video item):

```
multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"{'snippet':{'title' : 'TITLE_TEXT', 'description': 'DESCRIPTION_TEXT'}}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
```

the post url should also be changed to part=snippet

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet
```

i.e.

```
.POST,
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet",
    headers: headers,
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"{'snippet':{'title' : 'TITLE_TEXT', 'description': 'DESCRIPTION_TEXT'}}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"snippet", mimeType: "application/json")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: videodata, name: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")
},
```

Comment: This does work but only if you specify "&uploadType=multipart" as a query param

Comment: Plus Google's supports for multipart requests has a very specific format: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/multipart-upload (if you want the metadata included). It seems that in most cases, Google will simply ignore the included metadata if it's in an incorrect format in multipart requests

Comment: @Kalle get error ["error": { code = 403; errors = ( { domain = global; message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."; reason = insufficientPermissions; } ); message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."; }] How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I was able to upload a video with snippet data was through a combination of POST and PUT calls.  **POST** to upload a video with no metadata, and **PUT** to edit the video's metadata. Doing this requires a couple of things:

```
1. Enable the necessary scopes
    -https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload for POST
    -https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube for PUT
2. Be mindful of the URL's you use for each request
    -https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet for POST
    -https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=\(ios_key) for PUT
```

Now, if you're using Alamofire the POST you've included in your question can remain as is.  For the PUT portion, you have to be mindful of how Alamofire wants the parameters to be passed:

```
request(<#T##method: Method##Method#>, <#T##URLString: URLStringConvertible##URLStringConvertible#>, parameters: <#T##[String : AnyObject]?#>, encoding: <#T##ParameterEncoding#>, headers: <#T##[String : String]?#>)
```

Notice parameters: <[String : AnyObject]?>  This is **exactly** how you have to define your snippet dictionary:

```
let dictionarySnippet :Dictionary<String, AnyObject>  = [
  "title" : "something in the way",
  "description" : "is this finally gonna work?",
  "tags" : ["whisky","tango","fox"],
  "categoryId" : "1"
]
```

You'll also have to send the uploaded video's id (which you can capture from your POST in yet another dictionary:

```
let dictionaryParameters :Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
            "id" : "\(returnedId)",
            "snippet" : dictionarySnippet,
          ]
```

Finally, you are now ready to send a PUT request that will update your video's metadata:

```
let putRequest = request(.PUT, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&key=\(ios_key)", parameters: dictionaryParameters, encoding: .JSON , headers: headers)
```

Comment: Glad you finally figured this out and thanks for posting!

Comment: @user3344977 get error ["error": { code = 403; errors = ( { domain = global; message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."; reason = insufficientPermissions; } ); message = "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."; }] How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://gist.github.com/forderud/941e1d2014c43a0e3f5f0af1d7972075 for Qt/C++ sample code showing how to upload a video to YouTube, including snippet metadata. C++ is of course not Swift, but it should be similar to a Swift implementation.