# Upload video to youTube from iOS application in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, upload

I'm working on an iOS application and need to upload video to YouTube from iOS Application(My Custom Application) . Is there any way I can do this.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053431/upload-video-to-youtube-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload Video to YouTube in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053431/upload-video-to-youtube-in-swift)