# Uploading video on youtube from iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, youtube-data-api

I want to upload video on Youtube from my own app & also resume the uploads after killing apps & even in background mode. I have tried this link but this is a MacApp and not a iOS app. Also when I run it, it says in pod file **NSURLSession is available in 10.9 or newer**. So it does not seems to be working for me.

https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/tree/master/Examples

Can any one guide me how can I achieve this in a Better and maybe a straightforward example.

**EDIT:**
I have tried below code and I am getting below error. kindly help me in resolving issue.

```
func postVideoToYT(videoData: Data, token: String,title:String,innoId:Int,videoTags:String,callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        do {

            let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]

            upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                multipartFormData.append("{'snippet':{'title' : '\(title)','description': 'abc'}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "snippet", mimeType: "application/json")

                multipartFormData.append("{'status' : {'privacyStatus':'private'}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "status",mimeType: "application/json")

                multipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mov", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")

            }, usingThreshold: 1, to: URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&status")!, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {

                case .success(let upload, _, _):



                    upload.responseJSON { response in

                        print("Post video to url --->\(response)")

                        if let json = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {

                            let videoId = json["id"] as? String ?? ""

                           /* self.delayWithSeconds(1, completion: {

                                self.addVideo(innoId: innoId, videoKey:videoId, shortDesc: title, tagIds: videoTags)

                            })*/

                        }



                        callback(true)

                    }



                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                        print(progress)

                       // self.progressView.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)

                        //self.progressLabel.text = "\(( Int(progress.fractionCompleted * 100)))%"

                    })



                    break

                case .failure(_):

                    callback(false)

                    break

                }

            })

        }



        catch {

            print("Catch error")

        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: To upload the video: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053431/upload-video-to-youtube-in-swift you can refer this link

Comment: Do we need to use only rest api. can not we use classes as mentioned on above link ?

Comment: What does the "upload" method contain?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function on iOS10 and iOS12 and it is working.
I suspect that the problem is coming from a wrong token (Authorization in the header section).
Please note that the token is changing every time you do a Google Signin