# iOS Swift 4: Uploading Videos to YouTube

Tags: ios, swift, upload, youtube-api

I am trying to implement a feature where users can upload a video to YouTube directly from the app, sort of like a share to Twitter or Facebook type way. I don't want to use the UIShareViewController, I want to allow it to be upload-able with the touch of one button.

I have done some research, and all the other posts are outdated, mostly in 2014. I am looking for a new version using Swift 4. I understand the whole process of registering my app through Google to get the API, I have looked at their documents. However, their section on uploading videos requires Python 2.5 or higher, so I am not sure where to go about it.

This is a link to their API: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

I found these questions, but they are outdated.

[Upload Video to YouTube in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053431/upload-video-to-youtube-in-swift)

1. Are there any updated resources online that can help me?
2. A brief description of the process after registering the app with the Api would help.

Comment: Have you checked out this document about uploading a video, it seems to have quite a few alternatives to python, most would be extensible to Swift with Alamofire?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.